# Work done by force moving a pendulum

Tags: forces, energy, potential, work, velocity

So there's this problem I can't understand where I need to calculate the work done by force F to move the pendulum at a constant speed from one point to the other. The correct answer is mgL(1 - cos(θ)), which is the variation of gravitational potential energy. But why is it so? My initial thought was to use the formula for work (F*d*cos(θ)), however, the angle between the force and the motion keeps changing.

Also, what difference would it make if the ball was moving at a variable speed?

Any help is appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do it by your suggested method, you could do it by a straightforward integration: $W=\int F\cdot dx=\int_{0}^{\theta_0}FL\hspace{1mm} d\theta=L\int_{0}^{\theta_0}mg\sin{\theta}\hspace{1mm}d\theta$ which would also give you the final answer. This is because the work done by the force to move it at constant velocity would be converted only to gravitational potential energy, ignoring air resistance. Due to the fact that F varies with $\theta$ to produce a constant velocity, you would have to integrate in order to find the work done if you wanted to do it by this method. If the velocity was changing, you would just have to factor in the changing kinetic energy into the equation.

Comment: Thanks, but why is F=mgsin(θ)? In order for the ball to move at constant velocity, the net force acting on it should be zero. So, the vertical component of the rope tension should be mg and the horizontal component should be mgtan(θ), which F should be equal to.

Comment: I think I figured it out, mgsin(θ) is the tangential component of F, the component of F which does work.